# How do you obtain a Auth token using webView in android?

Tags: java, android

I need to receive the token on my Android aplication..
I created and API on laravel, and i need to receive a token, but i dont know how to do it on android.

Comment: this is my login Activity with URL

Comment: https://pastebin.com/T1QQyJtL

Comment: How can i receive the token here?

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to read a token into a WebView and then try to extract it from the WebView.  Typically, you just make an HTTP Request to an API method to get the token, then store the token for later use.  Here is an example of doing that, which doesn't involve using the WebView:

```
// You need a URL to an API method that will return the token
if (apiToken.length() == 0) {
    getToken("https://mycompany.com/account-services/api/v1/token");
} 



private void getToken(String url) {


    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {

                    // Response JSON contains the token
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    apiToken = obj.getString("access_token");

                    // Save the token in the shared appPrefs so it can be referenced in other classes
                    SharedPreferences appPrefs = getSharedPreferences("appPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);

                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appPrefs.edit();
                    prefsEditor.putString("apiToken", apiToken);

                    prefsEditor.commit();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("myapp", "JSONException Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("myapp", "Response Error: " + error.toString());
                }
        }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
        {  
                // Most Token API methods have their own secret user id and password 
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
                params.put("grant_type", "password");
                params.put("username", "apiusername");
                params.put("password", "apipassword");

                return params;  
        }

       @Override
       public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
           HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // This API expects the parameters in the form of "grant_type=password&username=apiusername&password=apipassword"
                headers.put("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
           return headers;
       }

    };

    // the Request Queue has been declared in the Application object on app startup         
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);

}
```